# Summernote insert quote

Tags: javascript, quote, summernote

I'm using summernote wysiwyg editor and I need to insert quotes.
In docs I didn't find way how to insert something like this, I tried with insertNode, but it returns **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined** only way I found that insertNode works only for empty document.createElement.

I've tried with summernote('code', quote); too, but it just replace content. I even tried to create new element, add class and add contents, but still getting same toUpperCase error.

Here is something I've tried already.

```
function quote(post) {
    var entry   =   $(post),
        author  =   entry.find('.quotable-author').text(),
        date    =   entry.find('.quotable-date').text(),
        content =   entry.find('.quotable-content').html(),
        quote   =   '<blockquote class="quote">' + content + '<footer>' + author + ' - ' + date + '</footer></blockquote>';

    $('.editor').summernote('insertNode', quote);
}
```

Is this possible to do in summernote or should I search for another wysiwyg editor?

Answer (score 3):

`insertNode` takes first argument as element not string. You can create element with jquery easily.

```
var quote = $('<blockquote class="quote">hello<footer>world</footer></blockquote>')[0];
$('.editor').summernote('insertNode', quote);
```

http://summernote.org/deep-dive/#insertnode

Comment: Thanks, this work, but why does it return Uncaught TypeError: quote is not a function on next time I wanna use that function on same editor in same page?

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Please explain more detail.

Comment: Im using that function quote to add quoted posts into editor works like this <a onclick="quote(postID)">quote me</a> On first insertion it works like charm, but on next or others it just return quote is not a function.